# Right way to list entries within a category (that's specified within a URL)

Tags: categories, gwcode-categories

Going through old templates and trying to clean up some stuff.

One page I have is a category page. This displays a list of entries within a category that is specified within segment 3 of a url like so `example.com/walks/category/myexamplecategory`

My template is currently like so (some bits stripped out)...

```
{exp:gwcode_categories channel="walks" cat_url_title="{segment_3}" output_depth="1" entry_count="yes"}
<h5 class="headline">{cat_name}</h5>
  <p>We have <strong>{entry_count}</strong> 
  {if entry_count == 1}walk{/if}
  {if entry_count != 1}walks{/if} in <strong>{cat_name}</strong>
  </p>
{/exp:gwcode_categories}
{exp:cat2:id category_url_title="{segment_3}" category_group="2" parse="inward"}
  {exp:channel:entries channel="walks" status="open" category="{category_id}" disable="member_data|category_fields" show_expired="yes" paginate="bottom" limit="12"}
    <h2><a href="{title_permalink='walks/view'}">{title}</a></h2>
    <p>{description}</p>
    {categories}
        <a href="{path='walks'}">{category_name}</a></span>
    {/categories}
  {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:cat2:id}
```

So as you can see, I'm using Cat2 and GWCode plugins. I'm wondering if theres a simpler way to achieve this, potentially using native tags as opposed to third party ones?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something here but this seems really straightforward. The following EE code would display all entries in the myexamplecategory category:

```
  {exp:channel:entries channel="walks" disable="member_data|category_fields" show_expired="yes" paginate="bottom" limit="12"}
    <h2><a href="{title_permalink='walks/view'}">{title}</a></h2>
    <p>{description}</p>
    {categories}
        <a href="{path='walks'}">{category_name}</a></span>
    {/categories}
  {/exp:channel:entries}
```

That wouldn't get your count of entries in each category that you have in the first chunk of code, but I can't see the point of the cat2 add-on in your latter bit of code.  So long as the URL is a valid EE category URL containing both the /category/ keyword and a valid URL title the channel:entries tag will dynamically filter to just returning entries in that category.

Comment: Tyanks for sharing this. I tidied this up the other day by dropping the Cat2 part and using `category="{segment_3_category_id}"` (as I have the Low Seg2cat plugin). You've just made me realise that I didn't need this either. I hadn't realised that the entries tag will dynamically return the correct entries! Super! Presumably for the first part to still have entry counts I need to use an addon/plugin. Still a lot cleaner already though!